# How do I fix Vetur type error Typescript / Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, types

I am likely missing something in the "TYPING" of my objects but despite my interface slot is coming up as an any type.

> Property 'slot' does not exist on type '{ slot?: number[] | undefined;
> tile?: number[] | undefined; cardOne?: number | null | undefined;
> cardTwo?: number | null | undefined; }[]'.Vetur(2339)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOTRS.png)

```
interface TableMatchInterface {
  slot?: (number) [];
  tile?:  (number) [];
  cardOne?: (number)|null;
  cardTwo?: (number)|null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding the "**?**" symbol after the slot property, typescript inferred that the object property could have 2 values, either number[] or undefined.
If you are really sure that you already have a real value and not an undefined one, you can use "**!**" to tell typescript to relax.

```js
siteStore.tableMatch.slot[0]!
```

You can have a look about the "**!**" symbol here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-

Comment: The error indicates `slot` doesn't exist at all, not that it's possibly undefined. Using that assertion wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `tableMatch` is an array of `TableMatchInterface` objects. Did you mean something like

```js
siteStore.tableMatch[0].slot
```

Either that or check that the typing on `tableMatch` is actually `TableMatchInterface`, and not something like `TableMatchInterface[]`